# MySQL: finding column_names in all tables of a database and modifying the content

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I would like to examine *every field* in *every table row* in a `MySQL database` and:

- see whether it contains a certain **REGEXP pattern**
- store the *table_name*, *column_name* and *contents* in a **separate table:**

`create sep_table ( pattern text, newtext test, tablename text, columnname text);`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: with dynamic sql involving querying the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) columns table.

Comment: avoid name-signing the questions. there's already a link to your profile tagged with the question.